# Read argument is C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to read parameters from URL in C# based Controller. But its giving error. I have copied the code and screen shot of the error.

In this code I am trying to read argument from url that is "hello":

```
using AxureAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AxureAPI.Controllers
{
    public class YNAController : ApiController
    {
        public ProjectDetails[] Get()
        {
            string value = Request.QueryString["hello"];
            return new ProjectDetails[]
          {

          new ProjectDetails
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Prj1",
                SvnPath = "svnPath1"
            },
            new ProjectDetails
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Prj2",
                SvnPath = "svnPath2"
            }
        };

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "But its giving error" is *never* enough information, and we really don't need a screenshot of a compiler error - please provide it as text instead.

Comment: @ckruczek -  It entered when I was copying the code otherwise nothing is there in my code

Comment: So I guess this is MVC 3/4? Please be as precises as possible with the used framework.

Comment: @ Jon - there error is   "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage" does not contain a definition for 'QueryString' accepting a first argument of type  "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage"  could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try to find it with `request.RequestUri`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the query string in WebAPI like that. Instead, it's much cleaner and simpler to let the MVC framework do the work for you and pass it in as a parameter. Change your controller method to this for example, so instead of using `QueryString["hello"]` you can access the parameter directly:

```
public ProjectDetails[] Get(string hello)
{
    //Now do something with the parameter 'hello'
    var whatever = "hello " + hello;
}
```

Now you can call your API like this:

```
http://server/api/YNA/Get?hello=fred
```

Comment: if I have more then one parameter then what I need to do, please share

Comment: Then just add more parameters to your API method.

Comment: No problem, but next time, please add the error message to your question as text, not an image :)

Comment: David I need your one more help - I have an external dll file. Where to keep that dll in my mvc 4 project how to add it to reference from visual studio

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    var query = message.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
    string key = query["Hello"];
```

Comment: Please provide more information and adapt your answer to the question. In the question there is no reference to `message` anywhere, so why do you have it here and what is it?

Comment: my bad @Knelis. my `message` is OP's `Request`.